# "UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template" views.py not recogniseing "RequestContext"?

Tags: jquery, django, django-csrf, django-floppyforms

I am working on an implementation of django-floppyforms, specifically the [slider widget](http://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html#a-slider). However I cannot get it to display in my django web application. The native slider will work but the jQuery slider will not. The below image shows the problem.

[image]

**The Error**

```
> UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the
> context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not
> using RequestContext.   warnings.warn("A {% csrf_token %} was used in
> a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is
> usually caused by not using RequestContext.")
```

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408545/django-csrf-verification-failed-even-after-adding-csrf-token), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078414/a-weird-django-error), [and this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050991/django-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect) all suggest making sure that the `django.core.context_processors.csrf` context processor is used, one of the solutions is to use `RequestContext` from `django.template`

As you can see below I have tried to implement it but it keeps giving me the same error.

Any ideas?

- Django==1.6.2
- django-floppyforms==1.2.0

**views.py**

```
def sview(request):
   jquery_slider = Slider()
   native_slider = SlideForm()

   return render_to_response('slider_one.html', {
                                          'jquery_slider': jquery_slider,   
                                          'native_slider': native_slider,             
                                          }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**slider_one.html**

```
{# slider.html #}
{% include "floppyforms/input.html" %}
<div id="{{ attrs.id }}-slider"></div>

<html> 
    <body>
        <h1>This is your slider_one.html template</h1>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/css/jquery-ui.min.css"></script> 


<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

        {{ jquery_slider }}
        {{ native_slider }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />               
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var type = $('<input type="range" />').attr('type');
    if (type == 'text') { // No HTML5 support
      $('#{{ attrs.id }}').attr("readonly", true);
      $('#{{ attrs.id }}-slider').slider({
        {% if value %}value: {{ value }},{% endif %}
        min: {{ attrs.min }},
        max: {{ attrs.max }},
        step: {{ attrs.step }},
        slide: function(event, ui) {
          $('#{{ attrs.id }}').val(ui.value);
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

**forms.py**

```
import floppyforms as forms    

class Slider(forms.RangeInput):
    min = 5
    max = 20
    step = 5
    template_name = 'slider_one.html'

    class Media:
        js = (
            '/static/js/jquery.min.js',
            '/static/js/jquery-ui.min.js',
        )
        css = {
            'all': (
                '/static/css/jquery-ui.css',
            )
        }

class SlideForm(forms.Form):
    num = forms.IntegerField(widget=Slider)

    def clean_num(self):
        num = self.cleaned_data['num']
        if not 5 <= num <= 20:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a value between 5 and 20")

        if not num % 5 == 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Enter a multiple of 5")
        return num
```

EDIT:

I also have the below enabled in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES of my settings.py file

```
django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. As @professorDante said, you need:

```
return render(request, "slider_one.html", local())
```

The key is that the request object must be passed to the template in order to generate csrf.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the render() shortcut - you're wanting to use a RequestContext, and that method uses one by default. If it works, you know it's your implementation of return_to_render.

```
from django.shortcuts import render 

return render(request, "slider_one.html",{'jquery_slider':jquery_slider,'native_slider':native_slider})
```

Comment: Hi, I should have mentioned that I have already tried that before the `render_to_response` method. Unfortunately it does not work